# Rails Routes - Redirecting Paths for Deep Linking, hashchanges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the jQuery hashchange plugin for deep linking in an ajax app.

Before I had URLs like so:

```
http://www.site.com/groups/1
```

Now to ajax the site links all look like this:

```
http://www.site.com/#/groups/1
```

This has become a challenge as it requires modification to the link_to helper to generate links correctly. And I just learned that it messes with Devise, so if a user who is not signed in loads, http://www.site.com/#/groups/1 devise doesn't retain that URL for redirection after a successful signin.

So I was wondering if there is a way I can keep the existing URL structure and have the Rails Route file redirect certains paths like so:

```
http://www.site.com/groups/1
to
http://www.site.com/#/groups/1

http://www.site.com/groups/1/tasks/31
to
http://www.site.com/#/groups/1/tasks/31
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on solving for this use case w/o hacking everything up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't such way.

Hash "#" sign can't be sent to server.

Comment: Is there some way for the inverse task? `match "/#/blog" => redirect("/blog")` doesn't work for me.